# Split list by sub-string in item and preserving delimiter

Tags: python, list, split

This is the input:

```
[
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String'
]
```

This is the desired output

```
[
    [
        '@imp_Some_String',
        'Some_String',
        'Some_String',
        'Some_String',
        'Some_String'
    ],
    [
        '@imp_Some_String',
        'Some_String',
        'Some_String',
        'Some_String'
    ],
    [
        '@imp_Some_String',
        'Some_String',
        'Some_String'
    ]
]
```

The idea is to split the list if item `startswith('@imp')`
I tried but the my solution will create x,y problem here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple iteration

**Ex:**

```
data = [
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String'
]

result = []
for i in data:              #Iterate items
    if i.startswith("@"):   #Check if item startswith "@"
        result.append([i])  #Append new list with item
    else:
        result[-1].append(i)   #Append item to previous list

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['@imp_Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String'],
 ['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String'],
 ['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String']]
```

---

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String'
]

data = [list(v) for _, v in groupby(data, lambda x: x.startswith("@"))]
result = [i + v for i, v in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])]
```

Comment: This will raise an exception if the first item in the list doesn't begin with `@`.  Also, the desired prefix specified by OP is `@imp`, not `@`.

Comment: @TomKarzes. If that is the case I do not think you can correctly group the elements

Comment: It's not clear what's desired in that case, since OP did not completely specify the problem.

Comment: @TomKarzes: I have already given input and output. Its is exactly same. The only difference is `_Some_String` which is ugly RTF text which will not matter here. I you need more details, I can provide. Thanks.

Comment: @Rahul The question we were discussing is what you want it to do if the first list element does *not* begin with `@imp`.  There are at least 4 things it could do:  (1) Include the first part its own sub-list (i.e., treat it as if it began with `@imp`), (2) Discard it, (3) Report an error, or (4) Blow up with a list-index-out-of bounds error.  The solution shown here implements alternative #4.

Comment: Oh!. I didn't see it coming. luckily my list always starts with `@imp_` literally. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
k= [
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String'
]
from itertools import groupby
sol =[]
kk =[list(v) for  k,v in groupby(k)]
sol =[kk[i] + kk[i+1]for i in range(0,len(kk)-1,2)]
```

output

```
[['@imp_Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String'],
 ['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String'],
 ['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Join all the list elements into a single line, split it based on your delimiter `@imp`, add the delimiter back to the beginning of each line that resulted because of the split, and finally split each line based on space

```
>>> list(map(str.split, ('@imp'+s for s in ' '.join(lst).split('@imp') if s)))
[['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String'], ['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String'], ['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String']]
```

Comment: Nice. My initial solution (non-working) was based on this as mentioned in my question. You gave a working solution of my idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution with `itertools.groupby`:

```
l = [
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String'
]

from itertools import groupby

out = [[*g] for _, g in groupby(l, lambda k, d={'g':0}: (d.update(g=d['g']+1), d['g']) if k.startswith('@imp') else (None, d['g']))]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out, width=30)
```

Prints:

```
[['@imp_Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String'],
 ['@imp_Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String'],
 ['@imp_Some_String',
  'Some_String',
  'Some_String']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current list:

```
list_ = [
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    '@imp_Some_String',
    'Some_String',
    'Some_String'
]
```

Create list of indexes:

```
indexes = [ind for ind, el in enumerate(list_) if el.startswith('@imp')]
```

Get result:

```
res = [list_[i: j] for i, j in zip([0] + indexes, indexes + [None]) if i != j]

print(res) # [['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String'], ['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String'], ['@imp_Some_String', 'Some_String', 'Some_String']]
```